# Generating link for my flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any packages which will help to generate link for my flutter app that i am building.Like most of the app that we come across they give this option of sending downloading link to others , like GooglePay. Similarly I just want to generate link and nothings else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement deep linking for your application please refer to docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking